# Keras acc and val_acc don't change

Tags: python, keras

I have a model that I am trying to train where the loss does not go down and Accuracy is not increasing even after increasing epochs.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2048,kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_shape=(1405,)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_197 (Dense)            (None, 2048)              2879488   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_198 (Dense)            (None, 2048)              4196352   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_199 (Dense)            (None, 5)                 10245     
=================================================================
Total params: 7,086,085
Trainable params: 7,086,085
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

```
Train on 5289 samples, validate on 588 samples
Epoch 1/100
5289/5289 [==============================] - 4s 830us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1864 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1871
Epoch 2/100
5289/5289 [==============================] - 4s 803us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1849 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1871
Epoch 3/100
5289/5289 [==============================] - 4s 820us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1849 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1871
Epoch 4/100
5289/5289 [==============================] - 4s 809us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1849 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1871
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeBbX.png)

Comment: Why are you using relu activation for output layer. It should be softmax.

Comment: its an regression problem therefore I used relu in the dense layer. I even tried softmax but the loss does not go down and Accuracy is not increasing

Comment: their is not any particular path that you follow and get highest accuracy .you have to try all possible case

Comment: Accuracy makes no sense for regression, it is a metric only valid for classification